# Forms of strict reporting — what do Americans call them?

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology, translation

I had to deal with typographically printed sheets with some generic text and fields to fill in information by hand (dates, signatures etc.) or through printing (if you are lucky to hit the fields). Each sheet has a watermark, its own serial number, and is unique.

Literally translated from Russian they are called "forms of strict reporting", but I would like to know what a native English speaker calls them.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to a form or a picture of one?  Also, you may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Comment: As Lynn points out, an "official form" is a common term in America.  Sometimes an official form needs to be notarized by a notary public, who verifies that the information contained in the form is true and accurate.  Sometimes an official form needs to have the "official stamp" of an institution in order to be valid.  This stamp could take the form of an embossed seal, which is very difficult to alter or change in any way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am unaware of a special English term corresponding to that description.  We would call such a thing simply a "form" or a "fill-in form".  If it had some special bureaucratic significance it could be an "official form" or a "standard form".

Answer (score 3):

I would simply call that a "form."

Here's a Google Image search for "form": https://www.google.com/search?q=form&tbm=isch